# Google Maps API marker based on data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, google-maps

So i have a set of data in my database, the data consist of location id (loc_id), longitude, and latitude. what i want to do is to create a map that consist of marker from all of my location data. what should i do first to create this map? because this is my first time using javascript.
currently the code that i used to show the map :

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<script>
    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(-7.803164,110.3398252), zoom:10, mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: [Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3)

Answer (score 1):

You need to output the data in your database into javascript and then loop through them then add them to your map.

First get the data from your database and make it into a javascript array. FYI my PHP is very rusty

```
var locations = [
    <?php
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM sometable';
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $currentrow = 0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
             $currentrow++;
             echo '{';
             echo 'latitude : ' . $row[0] . ',';
             echo 'longitude: ' . $row[1] ;
             echo '}'.if(currentrow != msqli->num_rows){,}
        }
     ?>
]
```

Then on the javascript you need to loop through the locations array and create them as markers.

```
  for(var i = 0; i < locations.lengtht; i++){
      var myLatLng = {
          lat: locations[i].latitude, 
          lng: locations[i].longitude
      };
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Your title'
      }); 
  }
```